# The php code mail fields sending empty fields

Tags: php, email

I am trying to create a `PHP mail`.

It is sending mail to the inbox perfectly, But I don't know how to send my form field values in `inbox`. I have tried but it is sending the empty fields.

Since i am new to PHP please check

```
<?php
get_footer();
?>
<?php 

 $msg = "mail from" .$name;

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
mail("email@example.com","My subject",$msg);


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $to = "email@example.com";
    $subject = $_POST['phone'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
}
?>

<form action="" id="reservationform" method="POST">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" title="Your Full Name please" required>
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number" title="Please enter your phone number" required>
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's sending empty fields because you didn't pass any of the POST arrays' inputs in the message (body) and you're executing the `mail()` function as soon as the page is loaded.

Here is how it's done while checking for any [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) fields:

Notice I've changed `mail()`'s arguments and added a few conditional statements.

Side note: There appears to be missing inputs, so you will need to add those in yourself.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if(!empty($_POST['name']) 
    && !empty($_POST['phone']) 
    && !empty($_POST['body'])) {

    $to =    "email@example.com";
    $name =  $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $body =  $_POST['body'];

    $msg = "Mail from: $name\n" . "Message: $body\n" . "Phone: $phone \n";

    // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
    $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

    // send email
    if(mail($to, $subject, $msg)){
        echo "Mail sent.";
    }else{ echo "There was an error."; }

    }else{ 
        echo "Some fields were left empty."; 
        }
}
```

Consult the manual on `mail()` for more information, and adding headers since it may be rejected or treated as spam:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php